# sql server login error with username and password

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server 2008 R2. There is a login with

```
Username:dev Password:***
```

This was working fine from last 10 days but I dont know why suddenly it stopped working and showing an error message when trying to login :

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------
Cannot connect to ASHI-PC\SQLEXPRESS.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Login failed for user 'dev'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
```

Please help me. I have set the TCP port 1433 by using sql server configuration manager but thats also not working, I have checked my firewall and it is disabled, I have checked the sql browser it is in running mode I have restarted it but not getting the solution.

Comment: ... someone changed the password?

Comment: no not yet ...i am alone using this server on my local system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved by connect the db using windows authentication and after that

> rightclick>select restart 
>   also check that it is in running mode in configuration manager and click on stop and then again start .
>   in my case it helped me .

Answer (score 0):

18456 is a login failure message.  Is there any more to the message?  Usually you get a 'state' code with it, which will tell you what the problem is with the login.

Try adding the Windows account you've logged on to the machine with to the local administrator group (if it's not already in it), then try connecting to SQL Server again

Comment: some time it shows that -connecting successfully but there is no process on other hand of pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question is has anything changed from the last 10 days.

1. Are you the only person using this login? (Could someone else have changed the password/disabled the user).
2. Have you check that the appropriate SQL services are started.

Perhaps try and use SQL management studio and try and authenticate to that server/instance using the credentials and see if you receive anything.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx), although old (SQL 2005) but explains your possible causes of your error.